# select specific digits from csv file shell script

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
DATE , Name , Description
2012181605 , Meeting , Business Meeting with John
1911181200 , Eating , Eating with my wife
```

Date is stored as a number: In this example the date is equal to 20-12-2018 16:05.

I want to create a shell script where user types the date he wants to preview. In this case i want to somehow extract just the first 6 numbers which indicates just the date and not the exact hour.

That's what i tried so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "type the date you want to preview"
read date1
if [ $(grep $date1 text.csv | wc -l) -eq 1 ];then
grep $date1 text.csv
elif [ $(grep $date1 text.csv | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
echo "the date you typed doesnt't exist or isn't valid
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I added one small change to your existing bash script,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "type the date you want to preview"
read date1
if [ $(grep $date1 text.csv | wc -l) -eq 1 ];then
grep $date1 text.csv | cut -c 1-6   # this will only print 6 chars
elif [ $(grep $date1 text.csv | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
echo "the date you typed doesnt't exist or isn't valid
fi
```